# What is the intersection of this relation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, set-theory, computer-science

If I have to find the intersection of a relation: which per my class’ notes is a family, then the intersection of a family is defined as such:

∩F= {x : for all A, A ∈ F → x ∈ A}

Now if I have to find the result to:
∩{(1,2), (2,3), (1,3)}

Per the above definition, should the intersection just be the empty set? Because there are no common elements? I’ve been told it is {(2,3)}, but I don’t see how.

Comment: In your (correct) definition, F is a set of *sets.* But in you example, it is not. (Unless you use Kuratowski's coding of ordered pairs as sets, which I doubt.) And if you replace your parenthesis by curly brackets, then the intersection is the empty set indeed. I cannot see how the exercise could be modified to give {(2,3)}.

Comment: @AnneBauval We have interpreted the ordered pair (x,y) as the set {x{x, y}}, so by that definition the relation was defined as a family. Does that still make the intersection of the relation I gave the empty set?

Comment: Oh, that is what I said I doubted! But it still gives the empty set. Even $\{1,\{1,2\}\}\cap\{2,\{2,3\}\}$ is empty.

Comment: The intersection as written is empty. Only way it can be something else is if there is a typo. Can you share the source of the problem?